# How to manage authentication with multiple VPS's and GoogleApps?

Tags: acl, vps

I have a bunch of VPS's and every now and then I have to create another. Currently I use AWS, Rackspace and DigitalOcean as my IAAS providers. Most of them are Ubuntu-based. Besides, I have the users managed by Google Apps.

For each of the created VPS, I have to manage a root and a normal user, and multiple users must have access to the normal user credential. If a user is blocked (i.e. got fired..) he obviously should not have access to the VPS's anymore. Another must-have feature is to allow/block permissions by users group. The users group would be managed by Google Apps and the VPS's would only point to Google Apps authentication API or equivalent.

I want to know if there is such way of authenticating users in multiple VPS's using Google Credentials. This way, a user should do ssh john.doe@ to access the VPS, where john.doe is valid credential managed by Google Apps.

If there isn't, which is the recommended approach to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is a google_pam module on [github](https://github.com/zopefoundation/cipher.googlepam#id2) which was written to achieve what you want.

> This package implements a PAM module to authenticate users against a
>   Google domain. The following features are provided:
>
> Select any Google domain. Allow only users from a certain group. A
>   script to install all Google users as system users. Password caching
>   using files or memcached. Advanced logging setup.

[Setting up Google PAM on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using a PPA](https://github.com/zopefoundation/cipher.googlepam#setting-up-google-pam-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-using-a-ppa)

edit 1 reply to @gfernandes 2nd comment below.

I have checked the source code and it just lifts the admin-user/password straight from the config file at 2 locations, when checking groups and then in checking password.

```
        service = self.GroupsService(
            domain=self.config.get(SECTION_NAME, 'domain'),
            email=self._get_email(
                self.config.get(SECTION_NAME, 'admin-username')),
            password=self.config.get(SECTION_NAME, 'admin-password')
            )
```

I haven't time to investigate further right now, but would want to try with a  2nd restricted administrator, which could be trashed and or with an application specific password under two step verification. I have had similar thoughts myself.

Comment: It looks very interesting, tks! Do oyu know if there is any other way to authenticate the admin user than saving his password in plain text? I know the file will be only root-permitted, but I dont like the idea of having the Google Domain Manager account password in blank text in every single VPS that I create..

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as @XTian's answer there's also this PAM called [google-authenticator](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/). Setup [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/wiki/PamModuleInstructions) are also available in the project's wiki.

After building it simply add this line to your PAM configuration:

```
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

I also found this interesting PAM called [pam-face-authentication](https://code.google.com/p/pam-face-authentication/), which used image recognition to allow logins based on a user's face.